# Prevent tab stop on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, tabs

I am navigating around controls in an application using tab. But the problem is when last element is reached, pressing tab focus on address bar. Is it possible to remove tab index from addressbar and set focus on first element.

I am looking for something like this: But I could not find the way to access url object.

```
urlObj.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
txtMyBox.setAttribute('tabindex', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to programmatically check if the focus is on the last input box and set focus to first one using `.focus()`

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PWRF/2/)

You will just have to change this part `document.body.firstElementChild` with the element of your choice, or may be you could use `$('input').first().focus();`